# In the given figure below ABCD is trapezium with AB||CD and $\angle 1 = \angle 2$. Show that $AD = BC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueqne.png)

I have tried to prove triangle ADB and triangle BCA congruent or similar but was unable to. I tried to prove the following things such as :

1. AC = BD
2. DO = CO
3. AO = OB
4. $\angle A = \angle B ~~\text{or} ~~~\angle C = \angle D$

So that the trapezium is isoceles. I also tried using the property that $ar(ADB) = ar(BCA)$

Comment: What have you tried, try adding your efforts

Comment: *Hint*: You have $\angle 1=\angle 2$ and since $AB||CD$, you have $\angle DBA=\angle CAB$. Thus $ABD\sim BAC$. What can you interpret from here?

Comment: If angles 1 and 2 are equal then A,B,C,D lie on a circle.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.

Comment: And if a trapezium is cyclic, then it is a isoceles trapezium. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\measuredangle ADB=\measuredangle ACD,$ we see that $ABCD$ is cyclic.

Thus, since $$\measuredangle CAB=\measuredangle ACD,$$ we obtain $$AD=BC.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle ADB \sim \triangle BCA $ by AA. Then $\frac{AD}{BC}=\frac{AB}{AB}=1$